# Why can't I import GUI modules while others can?

Tags: python, user-interface, import, module, pip

I have a big problem with importing all **GUI, notification, visual modules and other noCLI modules**. When I import modules (believe me, I tried all sorts of ways to install individual modules) python tells me `No module named 'module'`, while CMD tells me `Requirement already satisfied`. Other modules work, I reinstalled Python and again the same problem. I tried it on a virtual machine and it works perfectly. I would not reinstall the system at the moment. I suspect my pip is broken? If anyone knows why this is happening and how to fix it I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: we've got to know more about your configuration - OS, system Python or a virtual environment, are these modules local or installed   - to offer any advice.

Comment: You need to check that the pip you are using is the one from the python installation you want to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first check that the module is installed in your PYTHONPATH or not. To do the same run this command:-

> python -c "import sys; print '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
> in sys.path"

If it is not added, then first add it.

If you want to know how to add PYTHONPATH click [here](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html)